# Check if 2 or more items in array are the same and delete one of them according to sorting number - Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting

I have a dataframe that has sorted codes according to volume and trade.

| Code | Volume | Trade |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ApplA | 500 | 1000 |
| Amazon | 1000 | 500 |
| Facebook | 250 | 750 |
| ApplE | 100 | 1500 |

```
df_samecompanies['Codes'] = see below
df['Volume Order'] = df['Volume'].rank(ascending=False)
df['Trade Order']  = df['Trade'].rank(ascending=False)
df['Trade Order2']  = df['Trade'].rank(ascending=True)
df['Max Ordered Number']  = df[['Volume Order', 'Trade Order']].max(axis=1)
df['Final Sorted Number'] = df[['Max Ordered Number', 'Trade Order2']].apply(tuple, axis=1).rank(ascending=False)
df.drop('Trade Order2', axis=1)
```

This code outputs:

```
       Code  Volume  Trade  Value  Volume Order  Trade Order  Max Ordered Number  Final Sorted Number
0     ApplA     500   1000   <NA>             2            2                   2                    4
1    Amazon    1000    500   <NA>             1            4                   4                    2
2  Facebook     250    750   <NA>             3            3                   3                    3
3     ApplE     100   1500   <NA>             4            1                   4                    1
```

Two same code were in the final sorted range (APPLA and APPLE). APPLA has 4 as "final sorted number" and APPLE has 1 as "final sorted number". Since, they are same code (APPL), I want to omit from the list the one with the smallest "final sorted number". In this case ApplE.

df_samecompanies['Codes'] consist of companies and their different shares.Like ApplA,ApplE and AmazA and AmazonB.

I have another dataframe which consist of same companies.(like amazA,amazonB and apple,appla). This df include only 'E' , 'D', 'A', 'B' as a last characters.

```
if same companies DF in DF(main df): 
   if last character == 'D' or 'A': 

 check final sorted number and who has smallest final sort number, delete another code from list
```

df_samecompanies =

| Codes | Code | Shares |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ApplA | Apple | A |
| Amazon | Amazon | Empty |
| Facebook | Facebook | Empty |
| ApplE | Apple | E |
| AmazA | Amazon | A |
| AmazonB | Amazon | B |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `df_companies` dataframe to group same rows and keep only the best ranking for each group.

Input data:

```
>>> df
       Code  Volume  Trade  Volume Order  Trade Order  Max Ordered Number  Final Sorted Number
0     ApplA     500   1000           2.0          2.0                 2.0                  4.0
1    Amazon    1000    500           1.0          4.0                 4.0                  2.0
2  Facebook     250    750           3.0          3.0                 3.0                  3.0
3     ApplE     100   1500           4.0          1.0                 4.0                  1.0

>>> df_companies
      Codes      Code Shares
0     ApplA     Apple      A
1    Amazon    Amazon  Empty
2  Facebook  Facebook  Empty
3     ApplE     Apple      E
4     AmazA    Amazon      A
5   AmazonB    Amazon      B
```

```
out = df.sort_values('Final Sorted Number') \
        .merge(df_companies[['Code', 'Codes']], how='left', 
               left_on='Code', right_on='Codes', suffixes=('', '2')) \
        .drop_duplicates('Code2') \
        .drop(columns=['Code2', 'Codes'])
```

Output result:

```
>>> out
       Code  Volume  Trade  Volume Order  Trade Order  Max Ordered Number  Final Sorted Number
0     ApplE     100   1500           4.0          1.0                 4.0                  1.0
1    Amazon    1000    500           1.0          4.0                 4.0                  2.0
2  Facebook     250    750           3.0          3.0                 3.0                  3.0
```

Step by step:

```
# Reduce number of columns for readability
>>> df = df[['Code', 'Final Sorted Number']]
       Code  Final Sorted Number
0     ApplA                  4.0
1    Amazon                  2.0
2  Facebook                  3.0
3     ApplE                  1.0


# Sort rows by 'Final Sorted Number'
>>> df = df.sort_values('Final Sorted Number')
       Code  Final Sorted Number
3     ApplE                  1.0
1    Amazon                  2.0
2  Facebook                  3.0
0     ApplA                  4.0

# Merge dataframes on a common key: 'Code' for left, 'Codes' for right
>>> df = df.merge(df_companies[['Code', 'Codes']], how='left', 
                  left_on='Code', right_on='Codes', suffixes=('', '2'))
       Code  Final Sorted Number     Code2     Codes
0     ApplE                  1.0     Apple     ApplE
1    Amazon                  2.0    Amazon    Amazon
2  Facebook                  3.0  Facebook  Facebook
3     ApplA                  4.0     Apple     ApplA
```

Now, we have 2 new columns from `df_companies`: Code (renamed into Code2 by suffix) and Codes. Let's continue:

```
# Keep only the first row for each 'Code2' name
>>> df = df.drop_duplicates('Code2')
       Code  Final Sorted Number     Code2     Codes
0     ApplE                  1.0     Apple     ApplE
1    Amazon                  2.0    Amazon    Amazon
2  Facebook                  3.0  Facebook  Facebook

# Remove added columns from the other dataframe
>>> df = df.drop(columns=['Code2', 'Codes'])
       Code  Final Sorted Number
0     ApplE                  1.0
1    Amazon                  2.0
2  Facebook                  3.0
```

Comment: when you merge, the company in my other df is disappearing. For example, df_companies is not equal companies with df

Comment: Can I ask you something about suffix? How it works?

Comment: When columns have the same name from both dataframes, a suffix is appended to column names to avoid duplicate ones. I choose '' for left dataframe but I want the column names untouched and add '2' for columns from `df_companies`.

Comment: What do you mean by disappearing? The outcome is not what you expect?

Comment: when you add 2 for columns how could choose according to final sorted number?. İn your output, apple is in the list but, applA is left. How did you do? did you consider the final sorted number?

Comment: @Bianconera. I updated my answer with a step-by-step demonstration. The merge is performed on the same value name between column `Code` from `df` and `Codes` from `df_companies`. When 2 cells match, the corresponding rows of each dataframe are merged. I hope it's a bit clearer for you now?

Comment: when you do : df = df.drop_duplicates('Code2'), Why is the code below deleted?(ApplA). I mean ApplA has "4" final sorted number and ApplE has "1" final sorted number. But you drop the ApplA. according to what? what I want is that you delete the duplicates while you delete the one with the lower rank number

Comment: *Since, they are same code(APPL), I want to delete from list the smallest one who has the "4 final sorted number".* I deleted the ApplA because it has the smallest 'Final Sorted Number' for the same Code2 Apple.

Comment: This code always deletes the lower rank code from the list if there are 2 identical codes, right? thank you

Comment: Yes, exactly. `sort_values` sort by 'Final Sorted Number' and `drop_duplicates` keep the first element by default on 'Codes' column.